# Student Teaching of RP and NP HPLC - Labor practise

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am teaching pharmacy students in the instrumental analytics course and my main topic is HPLC. currently we have a (in my opinion) boring students experiment were the student determine impurities in a benzocain sample. for this we use a typic RP-18 HPLC.
We have also access to an SFC System which works very similar to normal phase.

I want to add an experiment where I can show them the differences between NP and RP HPLC and if possible show of the advantages and disadvantages.

Do you know any protocol which we can adopt into our lab for the students course? For you information: the experiment can last up to 4h (measuring time not included).

Maybe you had some good courses in your university and know some good experiments.

Comment: The [Journal of Chemical Education](https://pubs.acs.org/journal/jceda8) presents often protocols *known* to work (tested in classes) and appealing for an introduction into a technique.  By keyword [HPLC](https://pubs.acs.org/action/doSearch?SeriesKey=jceda8&AllField=HPLC) there are for instance 164 records tagged as *lab experiment*. Back at school, the demos (on TLC) were extracts of carrots (carotenoids), and dyes (could be really something for RP!).

Comment: Hi, I had a look it. but I had the hope, that someone already did a similar experiment and could tell me his/her experience or give some recommendations (analytes, mobile phase etc)

Comment: If there are literature databases about (HP)TLC (example [CAMAG](https://www.camag.com/user/bibliography-service)) then possibly the manufacturers of the NP/RP HPLC columns equally have ones.  Mark Perri's chemcompute.org runs *an ajustable simulation* of a HPLC of caffeine/acetaminophene/aspirine ([link](https://chemcompute.org/simulations/submit/HPLC+Simulation%3A++Separation+of+caffeine%2C+acetaminophen%2C+and+aspirin+in+Excedrin), described in [2020JChemEduc2950](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jchemed.0c00565)) so there should be enough data out there, maybe some did the comparison NP vs RP.